Salesforce Customer Chat refresh preChat field on click of a button
How to refresh the extraPrechatFormDetails details once the chat bot is loaded but before opening the chat window? I want to refresh the details on click of a button before the chat window opens.
Reference
I have tried resetting these details(below) on click of a button but it doesn't yield required result (the updated values doesn't get passed).
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails=[{....}]

